# python error: "index error: string index out of range"

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have got a problem with my code. I am getting an error when I trying to find the index in the element of `progId` from the array.

When I try this:

```
for index in range(0, self.channel_count):
    test = progId[index]
    test_index = index
    print test
```

The error are jumping on this line:

```
test = progId[index]
```

The error is: IndexError: string index out of range

Here is the full code:

```
self.channel_count = 0

if start_time < current_time < stop_time:
    print "program is half way"
    progId = list()

    for index in range(0, self.channel_count):
        test = progId[index]
        test_index = index
        print test_index
self.channel_count += 1
```

Here is the list of values from the `self.channel_count`

```
19:13:23 T:6056  NOTICE: 0
19:13:23 T:6056  NOTICE: 1
19:13:23 T:6056  NOTICE: 2
19:13:23 T:6056  NOTICE: 3
19:13:23 T:6056  NOTICE: 4
19:13:23 T:6056  NOTICE: 5
19:13:23 T:6056  NOTICE: 6
```

Here is the list of element from the `progId` list:

```
19:16:40 T:2112  NOTICE: 3003
19:16:40 T:2112  NOTICE: 3131
19:16:40 T:2112  NOTICE: 3259
19:16:40 T:2112  NOTICE: 3387
19:16:40 T:2112  NOTICE: 3515
19:16:40 T:2112  NOTICE: 3643
19:16:40 T:2112  NOTICE: 3771
```

Can you please tell me how to fix the error?

**Edit: When I try this:**

```
program_index = str(self.program_index)

for index in program_index:
    print index
```

I am getting this as the values by using `program_index`:

```
19:51:01 T:2888  NOTICE: 1
19:51:01 T:2888  NOTICE: 2
19:51:01 T:2888  NOTICE: 3
19:51:01 T:2888  NOTICE: 4
```

Here is the list of element from the `progId` list:

```
19:16:40 T:2112  NOTICE: 3003
19:16:40 T:2112  NOTICE: 3131
19:16:40 T:2112  NOTICE: 3259
19:16:40 T:2112  NOTICE: 3387
19:16:40 T:2112  NOTICE: 3515
19:16:40 T:2112  NOTICE: 3643
19:16:40 T:2112  NOTICE: 3771
```

I want to get the results like this:

```
19:16:40 T:2112  NOTICE: 3131
19:16:40 T:2112  NOTICE: 3259
19:16:40 T:2112  NOTICE: 3387
19:16:40 T:2112  NOTICE: 3515
```

So How I can find the elements from the arrays using the index?

Comment: There are nearly 2,000 results when I search for the exact error message on this site. Have you looked at any of those to see if they help?

Answer (score 3):

In the first run of your for-loop, `self.channel_count` is 0. So, `range(0, self.channel_count)` will be an empty list and you'll get the "index out of range".

Answer (score -1):

Just change `range(0, self.channel_count)` to `range(len(progId))`. It is not clear what the variables `self.channel_count` and `progId` contain.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, the variables `self.channel_count` is used for the list of values that start from `0` to `7` and `progId` contain is used for the list of program ids. Do you know how I can search for the element from the arrays using the index for the `progId`?